# PHP MYSQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

I'm having a little trouble with my MYSQL query

I have a DB full of products and I have a dropdown menu which lets a user select what time of day they'd like to get get results for :-

- Dropdown

  - Breakfast
  - Lunch
  - Evening
  - Anytime

At the moment my statement is

```sql
SELECT * from DEALS WHERE timeofday='post data from form';
```

Now this works fine, but with the option for 'Anytime' I'd like the query to be able to search for results of all/any of the above.

I was thinking of perhaps doing an IF statement which fires off 2 separate queries, one which says if the `$_POST['timeofday'] == 'Anytime'` then fire off

```sql
SELECT * from DEALS where timeofday='Breakfast' 
OR timeofday='Lunch' OR timeofday='Evening';
```

otherwise just do the normal query, although wondered if it was possible to do this in just one statement.

Kind regards

Comment: remove the WHERE, "SELECT * FROM DEALS"

Comment: I suspect your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: How do you know? can you see my code? I may have filtered all of my vars already ;P.

Comment: You could improve your second query by using `timeofday IN(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT * from DEALS';
if ($_POST['timeofday'] != 'Anytime') {
    $query .= ' WHERE timeofday="' . $_POST['timeofday'] . '"';
}
```

As DCoder mentioned, this approach is vulnerable to sql injection... You should check/sanitize the input or use prepared statements. In this case where there is a predefined set of values you can:

```
$knownTimesOfDay = array('Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Evening', 'Anytime');
if (!in_array($_POST['timeofday'])) {
    die('Unsuppotred time of day... Did it really come from the form?');
}
$query = 'SELECT * from DEALS';
if ($_POST['timeofday'] != 'Anytime') {
    $query .= ' WHERE timeofday="' . $_POST['timeofday'] . '"';
}
```

Comment: That was going to be my solution, is this the best way to achieve this? I wanted to see if there was a more elegant way of achieving it :(

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. I can see OP is familiar with it, but you should definitely mention it for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it can be done in one statement.

You are going to have to use an if statement anyhow.

Comment: Okay cool. Thanks for your feedback. I am not very good at SQL so thought there would be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

if these are the only 3 possible values for timeofday,then you can have an if in the php script like this:

```
if($_POST['timeofday'] != 'Anytime' )
    sql .= "where timeofday='".$_POST['timeofday']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

This could turn out to be negative depending on the items you have in the table, but you could use:

```
SELECT * from DEALS where timeofday LIKE '%{$post_data}%'
```

It would return all the results from `timeofday` if $post_data was an empty string.